# How to write One query for multiple groupings?

Tags: t-sql, group-by

In the queries below, how can I make just one query that will give me the results, instead of making copies with diff groupings and unioning them?

If possible.

Thanks in advance!!

```
`create table #temp1 (col1 varchar(50), col2 varchar(50), col3 varchar(50), col4 varchar(50), col5 varchar(50), sumit int)

insert into #temp1 values('AEAMS','CE Europe', 'Belarus', 'Govt', 'Int Fed Gvt', 1)
insert into #temp1 values('AEAMS','CE Europe', 'Belarus', 'Govt', 'Public Lib', 1)
insert into #temp1 values('AEDS','Japan', 'Japan C', 'Acad', 'CollUnive', 1)
insert into #temp1 values('AEDS','Japan', 'Japan F', 'Acad', 'Med', 1)
insert into #temp1 values('A- Regular Databases','UK and Ireland', 'Ireland', 'School', 'HIGH SCHOOL', 1)


Select col1 CC, null GM, null Terr, null Mkt, null Seg,  sum(sumit) SS
from #temp1
group by col1

Union

Select col1 CC, col2 GM, null Terr, null Mkt, null Seg,  sum(sumit) SS
from #temp1
group by col1, col2

Union

Select col1 CC, col2 GM, col3 Terr, null Mkt, null Seg,  sum(sumit) SS
from #temp1
group by col1, col2, col3

Union

Select col1 CC, col2 GM, col3 Terr, col4 Mkt, null Seg,  sum(sumit) SS
from #temp1
group by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [WITH ROLLUP](http://sqlandme.com/2011/07/07/sql-server-tsql-group-by-with-rollup/):

```
Select col1 CC, col2 GM, col3 Terr, col4 Mkt, null Seg,  sum(sumit) SS
from #temp1
group by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
with rollup
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83f70/3)